# remove style tag inside html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

how can i remove style tag inside html

i want remove complete style tag and css inside it
i try this:

```
  html = html.replace(/<br>/g, ' ');
        console.log('0='+html);
        html2 = html.replace(/<div>/g, ' ');
        console.log('1='+html2);
        html2 = html2.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
        html2 = html2.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

but this just remove style tag and don't remove css

[image: my style code]

Comment: why didn't you use `$('html style').remove()` ?

Comment: Solution above looks good to me

Comment: If ever there was a time for this, it's now -> [ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), that's horrible!

Comment: i use FreeTextBox and get text with : var html = ftb.GetHtml(); how use $('html style').remove()

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery `.remove()` method to remove any style tags from your **page**:

```
$('html').find('style').remove();
```

If the HTML is in a variable (**html**), use:

```
$('style', html).remove();
```